# How can I split very long case patterns across multiple lines?

Tags: string, bash, split, switch-statement

**How could I split the long valueX string in the following bash code?**

```
case "$1" in
    value1|value2|value3|...........more values..................| valueN)
        some_processing "$@"
        ;;
    ...
esac
```

I'm looking for splitting into separate lines.
M.b. like:

```
VAL+=value1
VAL+=value2
....
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the man page:

> A case command first expands word, and tries to match it against each pattern in turn, using the same matching rules as for path‐name expansion[.]

In other words, it's a glob pattern, not a regular expression. As such, you can use IFS between pattern tokens. For example:

```
case "$1" in
    value1 | \
    value2 )
        :
    ;;
esac
```

Note that you *must* escape the line continuation with a backslash, unlike the usual case where the pipe symbol will continue the line automatically. Other than that, you can break up the line the same way you would at the prompt.

Comment: You answer makes mine unnecessary.  Upvoting yours, removing mine.